# jQuery "live" validation of form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have recently completely recoded my site registration form, a lot of my users were complaining that upon registration, they would fill out the form only to be told that the username was already taken, or some other error that meant they would have to retype all of that information.

I set off today designing and coding the new registration page, and the resulting response from my users is that it looks more user friendly, and when the "live" validation is included, it will be just right.

Anyway, here is how my registration page looks, with the location of the divs that will contain errors;

[image: Image showing how the design of the form looks]

For each area of the form, I have added the **same div class** next to it, which I hope I can then hide / unhide depending on what the user has typed in.

My issue is, surely if I use that same class for ALL of the fields, it will update ALL of the error fields when I use something like the innerHTML function?

jQuery is far from my strong point, and I would really appreciate any help. I will add more information if it is requested, thanks!

Comment: You should start by instead repopulating the values the user already typed when the form is invalid (assuming you're doing validation server-side).

Comment: there are numerous validation plugins you can use that include remote validation of a field. Will save you time and trouble

Comment: By the way, just use this, seriously: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ Not to derail your learning experience but you are perhaps as they say "reinventing the wheel".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not give each field an id and use the selector `#whatever` instead of `.whatever` to access each specific field?

Comment: Are you suggesting giving each field a unique id? e.g username having #username-error? If so, that was my next step if I couldn't find another solution before doing that. Thanks!

Comment: Jake you probably already have unique values in the `name` attributes, why not use that? Also, seeing your script that actually generates the errors would be helpful... I don't think you need what you think you need...

Comment: @WesleyMurch hello there, thank you for your help. I am sorry to be a pain, I haven't got much jQuery / Javascript experience, I have enough to barely get by. My goal is to AJAX request the users desired username & email address to see if they are available, this is processed in a separate php script that returns a Boolean value. The rest of the values will just be validated using my own rules, e.g being required & being within the limits I set.

Comment: @JakeBall Yes, that's right--there might be other selectors that will work depending on the rest of your HTML. For example, you can make a selector that says a div that has a sibling or a parent with this other property to reach the right one without having to code in unique ids for each error field.

Answer (score 0):

basically you validate on events like `keyUp` or `blur` and when the validation finished you traverse the proper div by going up from the input element to the element that contains both, the input and the error div and then search for the error div by it's class. this way you'll be sure to only avitvate the error for the proper element.

assuming the element surrounding the input and error div (and propably label etc.) has the class `element` and the error div has the class `error`

```
$('input').blur(function() {

    // on error:
    $(this).parents('.element').find('.error').text('Some error occured').show();
});
```

if you validate using ajax the on-error stuff needs to be in the ajax callback ofc...
also need the same routine for successful validation: remove text and hide error div...